# Unable to set up nginx proxy to another URL

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, google-cloud-run

I have been trying to set up a proxy server to access content on megacorp.partnerpage.io on the URL https://gomegacorp.com/service-partners with the following constraints:

- The desired outcome is that the partnerpage is displayed but the url is still https://gomegacorp.com/service-partners
- Redirects for this situation are unacceptable, the config cannot be written with 301s in mind.

I wrote this snippet of an NGINX config....

```
location /service-partners {
  proxy_pass https://megacorp.partnerpage.io/;
  proxy_set_header Host partnerpage.io;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And I was getting 404s on partnerpages' website, and partnerpage was showing my gomegacorp.com/service-partners. So, this was progress.

Then I tried....

```
location /service-partners {
  proxy_pass https://megacorp.partnerpage.io/;
  proxy_set_header Host megacorp.partnerpage.io;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And got a white screen, but I'm not sure what was happening if the page was loading correctly. It would flash the proper partner page and then go away and turn white.

```
location /service-partners {
  proxy_pass https://megacorp.partnerpage.io/;
  proxy_set_header Host megacorp.partnerpage.io;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

This also gave me the same white screen.

Another snippet of info: This is getting deployed to an nginx container that acts as a frontend proxy on google cloud run.

I think there are potentially 1-3 issues,

1. My nginx config is wrong.
2. Cloud Run is doing something funky with the proxy requests
3. partnerpage.io is preventing me from accessing via a proxy and it needs to be set up on partnerpage.io (I don't have access yet)

Comment: Use the browser debugger (Inspect) to view browser network requests and responses.

Comment: I don't know if our problems were exactly the same or not... but in my case, updating `proxy_set_header Host my-domain.com;` was the part I needed to update. That value needed to match my `proxy_pass` domain, minus the protocol.